# unable to get all the data display checked in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a datalist which contain product catagory with unique ID asign to every products in my catalog. However, when i checked 2 or more checkboxes, i will only get the latest data display next page, but not all the data displayed. Just 1 data displayed only. Is there any way i can do so that I can pass 3 different ID at a time and display on nxt page?

```
void GetCheckedBox()
{
    foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
    {
        //access the check checklist
        HtmlInputCheckBox cb = li.FindControl("FavChkBox") as HtmlInputCheckBox;
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            ArrayList Product = new ArrayList();

            LblText.Text += " , ";

            LblText.Text += cb.Value;
            Product.Add(cb.Value);
            string url = "CompareProducts.aspx?prodId=" + cb.Value.ToString();
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

CompareProducts.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Product aProd = new Product();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_ID = @ProdID", con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdID", Page.Request.QueryString["ProdID"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        adp.Fill(ds, "Products");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        DataList1.DataSource = ds;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you are saying, but based on your code I see in your ForEach loop you have a response.redirect, so in this case you will only redirect to a single ID querystring.  You could switch your to use a session variable that holds a list of all the ID's the user selected.

```
foreach (DataListItem li in DataList1.Items)
{

    //access the check checklist
    HtmlInputCheckBox cb = li.FindControl("FavChkBox") as HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
    {
        ArrayList Product = new ArrayList();

        LblText.Text += " , ";

        LblText.Text += cb.Value;
        Product.Add(cb.Value);
    }
Session.Add("SelectedProducts", Product);
        string url = "CompareProducts.aspx?hasProducts=true;
        Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Then in your CompareProducts.aspx.cs on pageload if not postback check the querystring to decide if you should load the id's.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Page.Request.QueryString["hasProducts"].ToString() == "true")
            {
                ArrayList al = Session["SelectedProducts"] as ArrayList;

                if (al == null)
                    throw new ApplicationException("A product list is required.");

                if (al.Count < 1)
                    throw new ArgumentException("No products selected");

                string inStatement = string.Empty;

                foreach (var item in al)
                {
                    inStatement += al.ToString() + ", ";
                }
                inStatement = inStatement.Substring(0, inStatement.Length - 2);

                //Product aProd = new Product();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_ID in (" + inStatement + ")", con); 
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                con.Open();
                adp.Fill(ds, "Products");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                DataList1.DataSource = ds;
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: Hi there! I have error with this code:  adp.Fill(ds, "Products"); It says that "System.Collections.ArrayList" not found

Comment: Do you have a reference to system.collections on this project?